# Access service context in timer job

Tags: user-profile-service, custom-timer-job, timer-service, owstimer

I have custom claims provider which uses user profile service to get some data when resolving claims for user. I'm creating UserProfileManager this way:

```
private UserProfileManager UserProfileManager
        {
            get
            {
                if (_upm == null)
                {
                    SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.Current;                    
                    _upm = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
                }
                return _upm;
            }
        }
```

It works when I'm using gui for user management, because `SPServiceContext.Current` is present. I also have a timer job which performs some operation on user permissions, so it also uses my custom claim provider. The problem is, that there is no `SPServiceContext.Current` in `OWSTIMER` process and I can't create `UserProfileManager` instance.

How can I obtain service context for `UserProfileManager` in timer job (OWSTIMER process)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you get SPServiceContext:

```
public void UserProfileSample()
{
    //get current service context
    string websiteUrl = "http://SampleName";
    SPSite site = new SPSite(strUrl);
    SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);

   //initialize user profile config manager object
   UserProfileManager upm = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);

}
```

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilemanager.aspx)